# Android's BreakIterator considers line breaks as sentence delimiters

Tags: java, android, breakiterator

I have a unix text file that I want to read in my Android app and split it into sentences. However I noticed that `BreakIterator` considers some line break characters as sentence delimiters.
I use the following code to read the file and split it into senteces (only the first sentence is output for presentation purpose):

```
        File file = new File...
        String text = "";
        BreakIterator sentenceIterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);

    try {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
            stringBuilder.append('\n');
        }

        inputStream.close();
        text = stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    sentenceIterator.setText(text);
    int end = sentenceIterator.next();
    System.out.println(end);
    System.out.println(text.substring(0, end));
```

But if I compile and run the code from Eclipse as a Desktop app the text is split correctly. I don't understand why it doesn't do the same on Android app.

I tried to convert the text file to dos format, I even tried to read the file and preserve original line breaks:

```
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(".*\\R|.+\\z");
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(file, "UTF-8")) {
        String line;
        while ((line = in.findWithinHorizon(pat, 0)) != null) {
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        }
        text = stringBuilder.toString();
        sentenceIterator.setText(text);
        int end = sentenceIterator.next();
        System.out.println(end);
        System.out.println(text.substring(0, end));
    }
```

but without success. Any ideas?
You can download an excerpt from the file (unix format) here: http://dropmefiles.com/TZgBp

I've just noticed that it can be reproduced without download of this file. Just create a string that has line breaks inside sentences (e.g. `"Hello, \nworld!"`) and run an instrumented test. If `BreakIterator` is used in a usual test then it splits correctly.

I expect 2 sentences:

**sentence 1:**

> Foreword
>
> IF a colleague were to say to you, Spouse of me this night today
>   manufactures the unusual meal in a home.

**sentence 2:**

> You will join?

Yes, they don't look great but at least you know why it is so (sentence delimiters are ?. etc.). But if the code runs on Android it creates a sentence even from

> Foreword

for some reason...

I'm not sure whether it is a bug, or whether there is a workaround for this. But in my eyes it makes Android version of `BreakIterator` as sentence splitter useless as it is normal for sentences in books to spread over multiple lines.

In all the experiments I've used the same `import java.text.BreakIterator;`

Comment: What is it you are expecting? only the `Foreword` line? or the first sentence too?

Comment: And what output do you get when running on Android?

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer but it might give you some insights.

It is not a file encoding issue, I tried it it his way and have the same faulty behaviour.

```
BreakIterator sentenceIterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US);
String text = "Foreword\nIf a colleague were to say to you, Spouse of me this night today manufactures the unusual meal in a home. You will join?";
sentenceIterator.setText(text);
```

Android does not use the same Java version as your computer

I noticed that when I printout the class of the sentenceIterator object

```
sentenceIterator.getClass()
```

I have different classes when running with IntelliJ and when running on Android:

Running with IntelliJ:

```
sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator
```

Running on Android:

```
java.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator
```

`sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator` has the behaviour you want.

I don't know how to get Android to use the good RuleBasedBreakIterator class. I don't even know if it is possible.

Comment: Have you used the same import in both cases - java.text.BreakIterator ?

Comment: Yes in both cases `import java.text.BreakIterator;` but it is an abstract class and probably the implementation returned by `BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US)` (ie `RuleBasedBreakIterator`) is different on java JDK and android JDK. But I agree it is strange, might even be a bug in Android's implementation.

Comment: If I use BreakIterator In an instrumented test (a test that runs on an emulator) the runtime class is java.text.IcuIteratorWrapper and the splitting doesn't work as expected.

But if I use BreakIterator in a normal test the runtime class is sun.util.locale.provider.RuleBasedBreakIterator and the splitting works as expected.

Comment: No. I thilnk java.text.IcuIteratorWrapper is the culprit. I have already started implementing my own iterator. Another reason for doing this is that user should be able to set maximum sentence length because if it's too long TextToSpeech won't handle it.